# QR factorization of orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix $F \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$ of full column rank and $N>n $, we can write the QR factorization as $F=\begin{bmatrix} Q_1\; Q_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} R\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.
In an an assignment I have come to the point where the next step is to use that $I-F(F^TF)^{-1}F^T=Q_2 Q_2^T$ with the matrix $Q_2$ being of rank $N-m$.

I know that $F(F^TF)^{-1}F^T = Q_1 Q_1 ^T$ and I therefore I should prove $I-Q_2 Q_2 ^T=Q_1Q_1^T$. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, we have
$$
I = QQ^T = \pmatrix{Q_1 & Q_2}\pmatrix{Q_1^T\\Q_2^T} = Q_1Q_1^T + Q_2Q_2^T.
$$